# Finding last event in the group

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is the structure with sample data of my table (tracking_data). I want to find all the parcels which are undeliverable (cte_tracking_status_id = 10013) at the end (there are some). Below is the example of one parcel with it's states changes.

```
CREATE TABLE tracking_data_event
(
    cte_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tracking_data_event_cte_id_seq'::regclass),
    cte_tracking_number text NOT NULL,
    cte_tracking_status_id smallint NOT NULL,
    cte_timestamp timestamp without time zone,
    cte_description text,
    CONSTRAINT tracking_data_event_pkey PRIMARY KEY (cte_id)
)
```

Postgres version: 9.5

```
cte_id | cte_tracking_number | cte_tracking_status_id | cte_timestamp | cte_description  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
8546809 | CO-141998094  |   1   | 19-04-2017 |  LABEL_PRINTED  
8708871 | CO-141998094  | 10014 | 19-04-2017 |    
9519695 | CO-141998094  | 10014 | 27-04-2017 |    
8708872 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 27-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_PARCEL_PROCESSED  
9519745 | CO-141998094  | 10014 | 27-04-2017 |    
8708933 | CO-141998094  | 10010 | 27-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_PARCEL_STORED  
9519781 | CO-141998094  | 10014 | 27-04-2017 |    
8708969 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 27-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_PARCEL_PROCESSED  
8728290 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 27-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_TRANSIT  
8728291 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 27-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_TRANSIT  
9519829 | CO-141998094  | 10014 | 27-04-2017 |    
8728292 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 27-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_PARCEL_PROCESSED  
8743559 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 28-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_TRANSIT  
8743560 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 28-04-2017 |  BPOST_LM_TRANSIT  
8767949 | CO-141998094  | 10009 | 01-05-2017 |  BPOST_LM_MISSED_DELIVERY  
9519855 | CO-141998094  | 10013 | 01-05-2017 |  BPOST_LM_UNDELIVERABLE  
8767950 | CO-141998094  | 10004 | 01-05-2017 |  BPOST_LM_TRANSIT  
8789169 | CO-141998094  | 20    | 02-05-2017 |  BPOST_LM_DELIVERED
```

Comment: the above example has `BPOST_LM_DELIVERED` as the last status, so this parcel is not in undeliverable status anymore?

Comment: Correct, this parcel is delivered. But there are some which has Undeliverable in the last (last ordered by timestamp).

Comment: Questions like this *need* an exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) showing data types and constraints. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

If by "last" you mean the last ordered by the timestamp, then you can do this in several ways.  One method uses `distinct on`:

```
select t.*
from (select distinct on (cte_tracking_number) t.*
      from t
      order by cte_tracking_number, cte_timestamp desc
     ) t
where cte_tracking_status_id = 10013;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you query. But, when I am running it, I am not getting any data. I changed the 't' with my table name.

Comment: @ashutoshsingh . . . The `order by` should be descending on the timestamp column.